CKEditor5 sanitizes HTML in a way that alters the structure of anchor tags
When sanitizing or normalizing HTML content in CKEditor5, the following HTML is altered.
Original HTML:
<a href="https://www.google.it" target="_blank">
  <i class="fab fa-whatsapp"></i>
</a>
<a class="share-mobile-link" onclick="SocialShare('test')">
  <i class="fas fa-share-alt"></i>
</a>

After sanitization (when i switch between source editing mode and "normal" mode), the second anchor tag is altered, becoming:
<i class="fas fa-share-alt">
  <a class="share-mobile-link" onclick="SocialShare('test')"></a>
</i>

This is a part of my CKEditor configuration, maybe it could help:
mediaEmbed: {
    previewsInData: true
},
htmlSupport: {
    allow: [
        {
            name: /.*/,
            attributes: true,
            classes: true,
            styles: true
        }
    ],
    allowEmpty: [
        'i',
        'a',
        'span',
        'div'
    ]
},
link: {
    decorators: {
        openInNewTab: {
            mode: 'manual',
            label: 'Open in a new tab',
            attributes: {
                target: '_blank'
            }
        }
    }
}

The strange thing is that the first anchor tag is well preserved, while the second one is altered. This inconsistency makes it unclear whether this is an issue with my CKEditor configuration or a deeper problem within CKEditor’s HTML sanitization process.
I tried to change my CKEditor configurations, i tried to edit the html but nothing worked
Thank you in advance for any help or guidance regarding this issue.
